# Как отключить в wine проверку на работу X сервера и всего прочего, что бы использовать его сугубо для консольных нужд?

Tags: linux, wine

В контейнер на ubuntu установил wine.
Мне надо запустить всего один экзешник со 100% консольной программой.
И программа даже успешно отрабатывает, но перед как она отработает я вижу это:

```
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
000b:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0014:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0014:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
0014:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0014:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 0
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:apartment_createwindowifneeded CreateWindow failed with error 14007
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x800736b7
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 800736b7
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 800736b7
0010:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0010:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
Could not load wine-gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: configuration in '/root/.wine' has been updated.
0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

Так то терпимо, но это ошибки прилично отъедают времени.
Есть ли какой-нибудь способ отключить все эти гуёвые проверки, они как бы здесь вообще не нужны?

Дaльше читать не обязательно:
*Конечно пытался разобраться сам, были варианты:

В конце команды с wine подставить "\nogui" - разницы не увидел 

Перед wine добавить "DISPLAY=:0.0 wine ./my_app.exe" - по моему тоже ничего не поменялось 

Пробовал wine cmd и wineconsole открывается типо эмулятор cmd но я не понял можно ли его запустить сразу со своей командой а потом зарыть, автоматизировать не получилось*

Comment: Рецепт из 2015 года: использовать консольный X сервер. https://superuser.com/questions/902175/run-wine-totally-headless

Comment: DISPLAY=:0.0 wine ./my_app.exe - перед этим надо сначала запустить х сервер.

Comment: @PakUula я предпочитаю xspice (можно xvnc и xrdp) чтоб можно было посмотреть что там на экране